# minimality of ideals generated by primes among the prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, prime-factorization, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have following task:

> Given a factorial ring $R$ (i.e. with unique prime decomposition) and a prime element $a \in R$ prove that if $I \subseteq R$ is a prime ideal with $(0) \subseteq I \subseteq (a)$, then $I=(0)$ or $I=(a)$.

So far I assumed that $I \neq (0)$ and $I \neq (a)$ in order to find a contradiction.

I was able to prove that no power $a^s$ of $a$ (for $s \in \mathbb N$) can be contained in $I$, so $a^s \not\in I\ \forall s \in\mathbb N$, but I'm stuck there.

Is this the right way to go? Or is there another easier way that I missed?

I'm glad for any hints or alternative solutions.

Comment: Suppose $I\ne (0)$ and $I\ne(a)$ and let $x\in I$, $x\ne 0$. Then $x\in (a)$, so $x=a^ku$ with $\gcd(a,u)=1$. From $a^ku\in I$ and $a\notin I$ we get $u\in I$, so $u\in (a)$ hence $a\mid u$, a contradiction.

Comment: I didn't expect it to be that short, thank you very much! Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.